# Opening a file from terminal only by typing its name

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I know that `xdg-open` will open from terminal a file in the user's preferred application like this:

```
xdg-open filename
```

But I wonder how can I open a file from the current directory in its default application only by typing:

```
filename
```

followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course. Nothing more.

Comment: Presumably you could modify the `command_not_found_handle()` function in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to check for and xdg-open a file in the same directory?

Comment: I can reduce some of your risk by using alias. alias open ="xdg-open" open is a variable simply. you can make it as short as you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use Ubuntu's `command-not-found` hook, as specified in [Command Not Found Magic](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommandNotFoundMagic). It is currently used to suggest packages to install. Refer to `/usr/share/doc/command-not-found/README` which should be installed on your system.

Better yet, because it does not depend on the `command-not-found` package, (re)implement the Bash builtin `command_not_found_handle` to do an `xdg-open` if `$1` is an existing file, and to delegate all other cases to the previous implementation.

```
# Save the existing code for the handler as prev_command_not_found_handle.
# Bit of a hack, as we need to work around bash's lack of lexical closure,
# and cover the case when it is not defined at all.
eval "prev_$(declare -f command_not_found_handle)" >& /dev/null \
     || prev_command_not_found_handle () { 
            echo "$1: command not found" 1>&2
            return 127
        }

# Define the new implementation, delegating to prev_handler.
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        xdg-open "$1"
    else
        prev_command_not_found_handle "$@"
    fi
}
```

Good question, nifty feature.

---

Thinking it over some more: you might not like the feature as much as you think, unless you also extend the `bash_completion` handler. Imagine wanting to open `file-with-a-long-name.txt`, then setting

```
alias o='xdg-open'
```

will make (about) four key presses suffice:

```
o f<Tab><Enter>
```

Whereas typing the full file name takes a tedious 26 - and that excludes backspacing over the inevitable typos.