# Change current working directory only by typing the name of the new one

Tags: command-line, bash

Something similar to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/364921/147044), I know that `cd` will change current working directory in terminal to a new directory like this:

```
cd /path/to/new_directory
```

But I wonder how can I change current working directory only by typing for example:

```
/path/to/new_directory
```

followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course. Nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just find out that by activating `autocd` shell option, using the following command:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

then

> a command name that is the name of a directory is executed as if it
>   were the argument to the `cd` command

(from `man bash`, somewhere at the line 5131).

So it will actually let me use any directory as a command and will `cd` to it:

[image: cd]

To make the change permanently, add the following line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior for `zsh` with the Grml config. `zsh` is an advanced shell, it has a lot of improvements over `bash`, the default shell in Ubuntu.

To install zsh, type:

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

To grab the Grml configuration, run this from your home directory:

```
wget -O .zshrc http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/zsh/zshrc
wget -O .zshrc.local  http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/skel/.zshrc
```

Then run `zsh` to start it. If you like it, you can make it your default shell by running the following command:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: I tagged my Q with [tag:bash], so I'm not really interested in [tag:zsh]. Anyway, +1 for your nice and clear answer.

Comment: You don't really need to grab that Grml configuration. The equivalent of `shopt -s autocd` from bash in zsh is `setopt auto_cd`.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Thanks for the info. I usually recommend the Grml config because it has all the settings people are usually looking for. If you're into fine-tuning your shell, you'll probably end up trying to mimic the zsh/grml behavior. After using it for 2 minutes, going back to `bash` is like the step back from `bash` to `sh`. (Your experience may differ.)